# React Native RNFS Readdir returning incorrect result

Tags: reactjs, native

In my android emulator Music folder. There are 5 mp3 files. When I called the following function, the Alert showing '2'. Meaning the readdir function returning only 2 result. I have no idea why this is happening. Tried many other options. Can someone share any advice ?

```
  const listMusicFiles =  () => {
     const musicFolderPath = RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/Music";
     let filelist = RNFS.readdir(musicFolderPath);
     Alert.alert(String(filelist.length));
     console.error(filelist);
  };
```

The console showing the following result

> [{"ctime": null, "isDirectory": [Function isDirectory], "isFile":
> [Function isFile], "mtime": 2023-10-07T20:29:57.000Z, "name":
> "Shadows.mp3", "path": "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Shadows.mp3",
> "size": 11302415}, {"ctime": null, "isDirectory": [Function
> isDirectory], "isFile": [Function isFile], "mtime":
> 2023-10-07T17:53:56.000Z, "name": ".thumbnails", "path":
> "/storage/emulated/0/Music/.thumbnails", "size": 4096}]

Answer (score 0):

Try duplicate the "Shadows.mp3" file inside "Music" folder and check if new one exists or not. We need to make sure that the problem is not with the files on your phone. Also try change your code like the following:

```
  const listMusicFiles = async () => {
    const musicFolderPath = RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/Music";
    const filelist = await RNFS.readdir(musicFolderPath);
    console.log("Filelist:", filelist);
  };
```

Comment: i've tried to copy "Shadows.mp3" to "Shadows1.mp3". Also changed the code as per recommended.

Comment: The result in the console as follows: 
Filelist: {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
 ERROR  [{"ctime": null, "isDirectory": [Function isDirectory], "isFile": [Function isFile], "mtime": 2023-10-07T21:23:59.000Z, "name": "Shadows.mp3", "path": "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Shadows.mp3", "size": 11302415}, {"ctime": null, "isDirectory": [Function isDirectory], "isFile": [Function isFile], "mtime": 2023-10-10T03:18:31.000Z, "name": "Shadows1.mp3", "path": "/storage/emulated/0/Music/Shadows1.mp3", "size": 11302415}, .......etc

Comment: The thing is why other files are not being listed ? I can play the mp3 files in the emulator.

Comment: Filelist: {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}

Comment: So, Shadows1.mp3 exists if you using your code? Try to rename other .mp3 files, check spaces in filenames. 

Also can you send files that not displaying in logs, maybe its broken?